# Interacting through dicts, grabbing their values and transitioning to a panda df

Tags: python, pandas, collections

I have a list of dicts

```
[{a:'jeffrey',b:'pineapple',c:'apple'},{a:'epstein',c:'banana'},{a:'didnt kill'},{a:'himself',b:'jebus'}]
```

What I want to do is transition those values to a pandas df. But as you can see a few dicts are lacking a few keys and therefore lacking values. So I took a glance at defaultdict object so I could transform the list object to something that pandas actually is able to interpret. And transform it into a dataframe.

```
dd = defaultdict(list)

for d in l:
    for k in d.keys():
        dd[k]

for d in l:
    for k in dd.keys():
        try: 
            dd[k].append(d[k])
        except KeyError:
            dd[k].append(0)
# Dict auto adaptavél
```

The code works, and folows the order given of those events meaning with the key is empty return a 0. But I was wondering if there better alternative or a code which has a better o(n) complexity

Wanted result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['jeffrey', 'epstein', 'didnt kill', 'himself'], 'b': ['pineapple', 0, 0, 'jebus'], 'c': ['apple', 'banana', 0, 0]})
```

Comment: *"you can see a few dicts have no keys whatsoever"* Where exactly? Or do you mean not all dictionaries have keys `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what i meant

Comment: why do you have a pandas tag?

Comment: Non need of multiple loops for that, `pandas` is smart enough to recognize missed keys in input dicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor and fill missing values with 0 then use `to_dict` method to export the dataframe as a dict of lists:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(l).fillna(0).to_dict('list')
{'a': ['jeffrey', 'epstein', 'didnt kill', 'himself'],
 'b': ['pineapple', 0, 0, 'jebus'],
 'c': ['apple', 'banana', 0, 0]}
```

Intermediate result:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(l)
            a          b       c
0     jeffrey  pineapple   apple
1     epstein        NaN  banana
2  didnt kill        NaN     NaN
3     himself      jebus     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a `defaultdict`? Just use the `get` method from `dict` and a default value:

```py
d_list = [{a:'jeffrey',b:'pineapple',c:'apple'},{a:'epstein',c:'banana'},{a:'didnt kill'},{a:'himself',b:'jebus'}]

dd = dict()

for key in [a, b, c]:
    dd[key] = [d.get(key, 0) for d in d_list]

print(dd)
```

Output:

```py
{a: ['jeffrey', 'epstein', 'didnt kill', 'himself'], b: ['pineapple', 0, 0, 'jebus'], c: ['apple', 'banana', 0, 0]}
```

You may also use something else for `[a, b, c]`, but I can't guarantee to know all keys given the list you've presented (not in a nice short way).

Comment: Forgot to mention, in my real example I dont know whichs keys are going to be returned

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but given a `list_of_dictionaries` you can convert it to a `pandas dataframe` using the `pd.Dataframe()` method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

You can then fill the dataframe with `0` value where a key is missing using the `.fillna()` method:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

While @B Remmelzwaal answer is also correct, iterating over lists through lists and dictionaries is not good practice, especially when dealing with large amount of data.